# Is $ \int _{1/a}^af'\left(x\right)×f\left(x\right)\:dx = 0$ true given $f\left(x\right) = bx + \frac{b}{x^n}$?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

In my math final exam earlier this week there was a function:
$$f\left(x\right) = 3x + \frac3x$$
And its derivative,
$$f'\left(x\right) = 3 - \frac{3}{x^2}$$
And one of the questions about this function was to calculate the integral:
$$\int_{1/a}^af'\left(x\right)×f\left(x\right)\:dx$$
Given that $a > 1$.

Doing this manually would give you $0$, but I was trying to find an explanation without actually calculating it at the time. So I wondering if that would be the case for all similar functions?
In other words, for every function $f(x)$ where
$x\ \ne \ 0$ and $$f\left(x\right) = bx - \frac{b}{x^n}$$ where $b\in\mathbb{R}$
is a real number and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a natural number, would
$$ \int _{1/a}^af'\left(x\right)×f\left(x\right)\:dx = 0$$
assuming $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a real number? If so can someone explain why? And if not then why do certain functions in the form I mentioned above act like this while other of the same type don't?

Comment: I don't understand the question either. If $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)$ is a constant, this is obviously false?

Comment: Do you actually believe that $\int_{1/a}^a f(x)\,dx=0$ for every function $x$?  What if $f(x)$ is a non-zero constant?

Comment: Note that $\int_{1/2}^2 \left( x - \frac 1x\right) \,dx \neq 0$.

Comment: @What makes you to think so? Did you mean area between the function and its negative in the same interval?

Comment: A pro tip: use \frac{a}{b} for $\frac{a}{b}$. Put it in dollar signs to do the inline equations! And using the { type of brackets is important. { works like an 'invisible' parenthesis in Latex so that your equations don't fall apart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I was able to solve this.

Considering a general function in which $b= 1$, one would get:

$$f\left(x\right) = x+\frac{1}{x^n}$$

Its derivative would be: $$f'\left(x\right)=1-\frac{nx^{n-1}}{x^{2n}}$$

Now, the integral

$$\int_{1/a}^{a} f'(x)*f(x)dx$$ would of course give $$\left[\frac{f\left(x\right)^2}{2}\right]_{\frac{1}{a}}^a$$ Writing the full expression, we get: $$\left[\frac{\left(a+\frac{1}{a^n}\right)^2}{2}\right]-\left[\frac{\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^n}\right)^2}{2}\right]$$ One can already realize that when you plug in $n=1$ the expression would indeed be $0$.

Simplifying the expression above: $$\frac{\left(\frac{a^{1+n}+1}{a^n}+\frac{1+a^{n+1}}{a}\right)\left(\frac{a^{1+n}+1}{a^n}-\frac{1+a^{n+1}}{a}\right)}{2}$$ This only satisfies the expression being equal to $0$ when $n=1$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Interestingly, it also works for $a = 1$ and $n = 0$.

Regarding $b$, it doesn't affect the value of the integral because it would cancel out in advanced calculations anyway:$$\left[\frac{\left(bx+\frac{b}{x^n}\right)^2}{2}\right]_{\frac{1}{a}}^a=\left[\frac{\left(ba+\frac{b}{a^n}\right)^2}{2}\right]-\left[\frac{\left(b\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)+\frac{b}{\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^n}\right)^2}{2}\right]$$ Which would again give $0$ if the conditions I mentioned above exist, no matter what the value of $b$ is.

So in conclusion, $$∫_{1/a}^af′(x)×f(x)dx=0$$ is true given $$f\left(x\right)=bx+\frac{b}{x^n}$$ When  $b\in\mathbb{R}$, but if and only if

- $n=1$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.
- $n = 0$ and $a = 1$.

And not for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So to answer the original question, it's not true.

Comment: @PineappleFish do you think this works?

Answer (score 1):

About the original question:

For an odd function, positive and negative areas reverse and cancel eachother out when integrating from $-a$ to $a$;

[image]

$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=0$

So, what kind of functions does your identity hold with? Well, if we let $F$ be the antiderivative of $f$, then we are looking for a function which satisfies

$\int_{1/a}^{a}f(x)dx=F(a)-F\left(\frac1a\right)=0$

,for all real numbers $a$ (-except maybe $0$ of course).

In other words, we have the functional equation $F(x)=F\left(\frac1x\right)$. Once we find a class of functions like this, $F$, all we have to do is take the general form of $F$ and arbitrarily differentiate it. I don't know how you would do this as of yet, but I'll keep thinking about it

**Update on this:** I have no proof, but a reason to believe that all such functions whose integral from $1/a$ to $a$ is $0$ are of the form

$f(x)=\frac{2x}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}\left(g(x)-g\left(\frac1x\right)\right)+\frac{1}{1-x^2}\left(g'(x)+g'\left(\frac1x\right)\right)$ for any function $g$

Which is quite strange.

**Update two on this:** actually I did something totally wrong in the derivation but oddly enough it worked for some random functions I tried in mathematica. I'll leave it up because I think I'm onto something, but I no longer strongly believe it to be true.

**Update 3:** Here's my idea (maybe someone can fill me in on this -):

If $F(x)=F\left(\frac1x\right)$ then $F'(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2}F'\left(\frac1x\right)$. Plugging in $x=1$ we get $F'(1)=-F'(1)$ which implies that $F'(1)=0$. Meanwhile,

$F''(x)=\frac2{x^3}F'\left(\frac1x\right)+\frac1{x^4}F''\left(\frac1x\right)$

But this adds no constraints if you plug in $x=1$. $F'''(1)=-3F''(1)$ though. Similarly, if you keep doing this, you find no constraints on what $f^{(n)}(1)$ can be when $n$ is even, and, when it's odd, I believe that it is a particular linear combination of the even powered coefficients. Thus if it's analytic, I suppose we can expand $F(x)$ with a Taylor Series centered around $1$. In other words, the odd part of the series is just some function of the even part of the series. Since a function is odd or even iff all the terms in its taylor series are odd or even - respectively - then each function has a unique expression as $E_1(x)+xE_2(x)$. Since shifting $F$, $F(x+1)$ is a McLaurin series whose 'odd' part will always be some function of it's 'even' part. Letting $F(x+1)=E_1(x)+xE_2(x)$, and assuming the desired condition, because $F(x)=E_1(x-1)+(x-1)E_2(x-1)$,

$E_1(x-1)+(x-1)E_2(x-1)=E_1(\frac1x-1)+(\frac1x-1)E_2(\frac1x-1)$

$E_1(x-1)-E_1(\frac1x-1)=(\frac1x-1-(x-1))E_2(\frac1x-1)$

"All I've done here is just solved for $E_2$"... Or at least, so I thought. It turns out I made an obvious mistake. But by coincidence, it is indeed true that if

$F(x)=\frac{x^2g\left(\frac1x\right)-g(x)}{x^2-1}$,

then $F\left(\frac1x\right)=F(x)$, regardless of what $g$ is. So I take back again what I said before: derivatives of these classes of functions do work, but I can't connect this to my original line of thought to see if that's 'all' of them which are analytic.

---

If you integrate $\int_{1/a}^{a}\left(x-\frac1{x^n}\right)dx$

$(\frac12x^2-\frac{1}{1-n}x^{1-n})|_{1/a}^{a}=(\frac12a^2-\frac{1}{1-n}a^{1-n})-(\frac12a^2-\frac{1}{1-n}a^{1-n})$

now we set this equal to $0$ to see when it's true.

$(\frac12a^2-\frac{1}{1-n}a^{1-n})-(\frac1{2a^2}-\frac{1}{(1-n)a^{1-n}})=0$

if we multiply by $a^{n-1}$, then on both sides we have:

$\frac12a^{n+1}-\frac{1}{1-n}-\frac1{2}a^{n-3}+\frac{1}{(1-n)}a^{2n-2}=0$

Since this is basically just algebraic equation for $x$ of the form,

$\frac12x^{n+1}-\frac{1}{1-n}-\frac1{2}x^{n-3}+\frac{1}{(1-n)}x^{2n-2}=0$

you'd expect it to be false except at a few special points that satisfy this equation.

So the answer is no, actually, in general, it isn't true. Integrals behave weirdly. Sorry I couldn't help more. But this is an interesting question though, I suggest you think about it more, maybe you'll come across something cool and interesting or deep.

Comment: Well, that's a very detailed reply. I'm glad that quite a few people noticed my mistakes right away. I'm new to this website and was hoping to get at least some thoughts but this really exceeded my expectations. Thank you so much for all the time you put into it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{1/a}^af(x)f'(x)dx=\int_{1/a}^a f(x)df(x)=\int_{f(1/a)}^{f(a)}u\,du=\left[\frac{u^2}{2}\right]_{f(1/a)}^{f(a)}=\frac{f^2(a)-f^2(1/a)}{2}
\\=\frac12\left(\left(ab-\frac{b}{a^n}\right)^2+\left(-\frac ba+ba^n\right)^2\right)
\\=\frac b2\left(\left(a-\frac 1{a^n}\right)^2+\left(a^n-\frac1a\right)^2\right)$$
so you want:
$$a^2-2\frac{1}{a^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{a^{2n}}+a^{2n}-2a^{n-1}+\frac1{a^2}=0\\
a^{2n}-2a^{n-1}+a^2+\frac1{a^2}-2\frac{1}{a^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{a^{2n}}=0$$

Comment: Which again only works when $n=1$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ as well as $n = 0$ for $a = 1$.

Comment: @libanobovich yes, which provides you with the full set of solutions